# How to serve static files with Caddy next to PHP Script execution? (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, sylius, caddy

I have a docker-compose based Server setup running PHP, Postgres and Caddy as Webserver/Reverse-Proxy with Auto-SSL that serves a PHP-Application (Framework Symfony 3/Sylius 1.5) with php5-fpm.

It works very well so far, but *not* with any static files like CSS, Images, JS and so on, although the `file_server` directive was placed.
Any static content gets a 404.

My application is copied into the folder `/srv/app`, where `/srv/app/public` contains `index.php` and `/srv/app/public/assets` contains static files (including several sub-folders).

This is my Caddyfile:

```
{$SERVER_NAME}

log

route {
    root * /srv/app/public
    php_fastcgi unix//var/run/php/php-fpm.sock
    encode zstd gzip
    file_server
}
```

I have tried to specify folders for `file_server` directive like:

`file_server assets/`

or

```
file_server assets {
}
```

each within the `route`-branch.

But this way, Caddy won't serve anything and gives 500er.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Let me know if you find out

Comment: YFI: we skipped caddy at all.

Answer (score 0):

For me, something like this worked (why this way, I don't know).

Directory is:

```
/projects/site
-- static
----- jquery
--------- jquery.js
index.php
```

Site can be accessed as: http://1.2.3.4:8000/site

Static files are requested under e.g: http://1.2.3.4:8000/site/static/jquery/jquery.js

```
:8000 {
        root * /projects/site

        @path {
           not path /site/static*
           path /site*
        }

        log {
            output file /var/log/caddy/site.log
        }

        handle_path /site/static* {
            root * /projects/site/static
            file_server
        }

        php_fastcgi @path unix//run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock
}
```